# Finding the Max of multiple score assigned to a student ID number

Tags: function, max, project

I am currently a teacher and I have a database containing hundreds of students. That database has student ID numbers, student names, and scale scores for reading and math tests as shown below. I want column F to display the student's highest score and column G to display when student tested recently. I want these columns to display these data by linking them through their ID numbers. I could do that if the ID numbers were not repeated but having the same ID numbers being repeated multiple times is causing me problems.

```
column A    column B    column C     column D     column E   column F           column G
ID number   last name   First name   Math score   test date   Highest score     Most recent test date
1705555      Smith       Joe          543          9/1/19       ?                     ?
1706666      Solis       Juan         459          10/8/19
1773333      Jackson      Devonte     654          10/14/19
1772222       Villa       Maria       329          9/4/19
1778888      Bilal        Issa        600          10/21/19
1705555      Smith       Joe          410          8/11/19
1706666      Solis       Juan         389          7/25/19
1773333      Jackson      Devonte     500          8/24/19
1705555       Smith        Joe         510          6/30/19
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you mean by repeated ID numbers? Do you mean that multiple students have the same ID? Or you have multiple entries with the same id and student being entered for test results? If it's the second, your database needs to be normalized. Your student should only be referenced through their id with additional details being recorded once in another table. Once that's done, a relatively simple sql statement (I'm not the greatest with that, probably just experiment a bit) should get you what you need.

Comment: I have multiple score assigned to the same student's ID number and I want to display that student ID number along with his name in one column, his highest score in another one, and his  most current test date. I hope this helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What kind of database ? What tools do you want to use ? Do you want to accomplish this with SQL or a programming language ? If so which one ?

Comment: Good point @polku, no idea what kind of environment this is.